# CView inplace editing of control layout

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cview

I have a `CView` that acts as a placeholder for several Ctrl's stacked vertically so as the occupy all available space.  What I wish to do is grab a horizontal boundary with the mouse and drag it up or down to resize Ctrl height.

The problem being that the child Ctrl's of the `CView` intercept the mouse messages and not the `CView` parent window (`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE` etc).  The Ctrl's also handle these messages for unrelated editing requirements.

Would anyone be able to offer advice or supply a reference to possible solution(s) to this sizing/editing requirement.  The situation is some what similar to the resource editor in Visual Studio.  Only I wish to edit in a live environment.

Comment: A link to a picture may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could easily be done as follows:

- Leave a small gap between the child controls (say 2 or 3 pixels). This could be drawn in the same color, or a slightly different shade.
- Set the cursor to `IDC_SIZENS` for the main CView.
- Handle the mouse messages (when the mouse is over that gap) in the main CView (down, move, ..).
- On 'dragging' resize the child controls.

That way all messages would still go to te child controls, except when the mouse is above those 2 to 3 pixel 'splitters'.

If leaving a small gap is really no option, than you would have to capture all mouse messages in the CView and check if they are on a border. If not, forward (or default) them to the child window below the mouse cursor.